# My app crashes on Android back button tap when the app is opened from nativescript-plugin-firebase notification message

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am working on a nativescript-angular application that receives [nativescript-plugin-firebase] notificatons.

The project is up to date. The package.json contains the following lines:
"tns-android": {
      "version": "5.4.0"
    },
"tns-core-modules": "~5.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.0"
"nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^9.0.1"

The notifications are fine but the app crashes when tapping the notification message if:

- the app is opened (in foreground)
- the device is closed
- then tap the lock screen notification message
- the app crashes
- and displays:

  ```
  An uncaught Exception occurred on 'main' thread.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
  ```

I have encounter the same error on Android Emulator and on devices having Android 7, 8 and 9.

[Screen error here](http://sites.collabrian.com/img2.png)

And here is the notification code inside src\app\app.component.ts :

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    /// *** Firebase Cloud Messaging ***
    firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback(
        (message) => {
            const that = this;  
            let contentId: string = "";

            if (message.foreground) {
                /** If the app is already open, show a dialog message. **/
                confirm({
                    title: message.title,
                    message: message.body,
                    okButtonText: "Open",
                    cancelButtonText: "Cancel"
                }).then(function (result) {
                    // result argument is boolean
                    if (result) {
                        if (message.data.contentId) {
                            contentId = message.data.contentId;

                            if (parseInt(contentId) > 0) {
                                that.routerExtensions.navigate(["/car-detail/" + contentId], { clearHistory: false });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
                });
            }
            else {
                /** Else if the message arrived when the app is in the background, this code is executed when the user taps on the notification. **/
                if (message.data.contentId) {
                    contentId = message.data.contentId;

                    if (parseInt(contentId) > 0) {
                        this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/car-detail/" + contentId], { clearHistory: false });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

    if (this.authenticationService.FirebaseToken == undefined || this.authenticationService.FirebaseToken == null) {
        firebase.init({
            // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging, see their respective docs.
            onPushTokenReceivedCallback: function (token: any) {
                console.log("Firebase push token: " + token);
            }
            , showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true
        }).then(
            () => {
                console.log("firebase.init done");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
            }
        );

        firebase.getCurrentPushToken().then((token: string) => {
            // may be null if not known yet
            console.log(`Current push token: ${token}`);
            this.authenticationService.FirebaseToken = token;
        });
    }

    // *** / Firebase Cloud Messaging ***
}
```

Comment: I doubt addOnMessageReceivedCallback runs inside Angular Zone, try running the navigation inside `ngZone.run(()=> { ... })`.

Comment: @Manoj: ngZone.run() makes no difference. In fact when the app is in foreground or is killed it works perfect. No errors at all.

Comment: Did you try adding some timeout, may be the navigation happens too soon before the frame is ready?

Comment: @Manoj: setTimeout( 1000) did not helped. I have tried to kill the process and reopen the app with

Comment: var mStartActivity = new android.content.Intent(app.android.context, app.android.startActivity.getClass());
var mPendingIntentId = Math.random() * 100000;
var mPendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(app.android.context, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
var mgr = app.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: But it takes too much time.

Comment: Not sure if we are on same page, what I meant was a timeout just before calling `that.routerExtensions.navigate()`.

Comment: I did the way you mentioned. But on the other branch else {} because the app is minimized and is considered in background. No changes in behaviour.

Comment: Can you share a minimal sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot. All pages are required to produce the outbid notification. But I can provide the app.apk. And a browser link that triggers the outbid notification.